# Real Analysis Question: derivatives

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

Let $$f''(x)+p(x)\cdot f(x)=0$$ and $$g''(x)+p(x)\cdot g(x)=0$$ where $a<x<b$.

1 ) Show that $W=f'g-fg'$ is a constant on $(a,b)$. 
2 ) Prove: If W$\neq$0 and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ where $a \lt x_1 \lt x_2 \lt b$, then $g(c)=0$ for some $c \in (x_1, x_2)$.

Hint: Consider $f/g$

Comment: Welcome.   What have you tried on this problem? What are your thoughts?  As a general rule,  problems that seem to be copy/pasted homework questions with no additional context/thoughts of how you've attempted to work on it/where you are stuck are frowned upon

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't even know where to start.  I'm drowning in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
f''(x) + p(x) f(x) = 0 \\
g''(x) + p(x) g(x) = 0  
\end{array}\right.
\rightarrow
\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
g(x)f''(x) + p(x)g(x) f(x) = 0 \\
f(x)g''(x) + p(x)f(x) g(x) = 0
\end{array}\right.
\rightarrow  g(x)f''(x) - f(x) g''(x) = 0
$$
then
$$1) \quad  W' = (f' g - f g')' = 0 \rightarrow  W \,\,\textrm{is a constant on } (a,b) $$

If $ \forall x \in [x_1,x_2]: \,\,\,g(x) \neq 0 $ then 
$$ 2) \quad \left( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right)' = 0 \,\rightarrow\, \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = c \,\rightarrow\,g(x) = \frac 1c f(x) \,\rightarrow\, g(x_1) = g(x_2) = 0 $$

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!